# How to write multithread into a single text file?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write both threads on a single text file, but it came out only the PrintNum part and PrintChar is not in the text file? 
How to write both threads into a single file?
Is there any way to combine both threads into a class so that it would come out to a single file?

This is my code:

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Multithread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Runnable printA = new PrintChar('a', 500);
        Runnable print100 = new PrintNum(500);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(printA);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(print100);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}

class PrintChar implements Runnable {
    private char charToPrint; 
    private int times;

    public PrintChar(char c, int t) {
        charToPrint = c;
        times = t;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        String fileName = "out.txt";
        try {
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                outputStream.print(charToPrint);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class PrintNum implements Runnable {
    private int lastNum;

    public PrintNum(int n) {
        lastNum = n;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        String fileName = "out.txt";
        try {
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            for (int i = 1; i <= lastNum; i++) {
                outputStream.print(" " + i);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both threads need to share the same instance of `PrintWriter`, which also means that you need to synchronise the writes so that only one thread is actually writing at a time

Comment: Please include what you get in the output file, and also any stacktraces that are coming out on the console.

Comment: It may make more sense to have "producer" threads write into a blockingQueue, and a "consumer" thread reading off from this queue and writing into a file.

Comment: ^^^^ what @Salil says. It's much more flexible, easier to debug and insulates the writing threads from the actual write, (and so any excess disk latency that might occasionally occur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Here I use append to file in print writer. I didn't do many changes  to your code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Multithread {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "out.txt";
    new PrintWriter(fileName).close();//to clear the text of the file
    Runnable printA = new PrintChar('a', 500);
    Runnable print100 = new PrintNum(500);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(printA);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(print100);

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
  }
}

class PrintChar implements Runnable {
  private char charToPrint;
  private int times;

  public PrintChar(char c, int t) {
    charToPrint = c;
    times = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String fileName = "out.txt";
    try {
      synchronized (Multithread.class) {//to writ by one thread 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(bw);
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
          outputStream.print(charToPrint);
        }
        outputStream.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class PrintNum implements Runnable {
  private int lastNum;

  public PrintNum(int n) {
    lastNum = n;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String fileName = "out.txt";
    try {
      synchronized (Multithread.class) {//to write by one thread
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(bw);
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastNum; i++) {
          outputStream.print(" " + i);
        }
        outputStream.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```